# Text Overlapping on Menu (Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with this Bootstrap carousel-caption that I inserted.
Here is the image of my web page, notice on the top right hand side that my article title is over lapping my menu.( That Menu pops out of clicked on the menu button). I want that title to go behind the menu.
[image: Text Overlapping top right hand side]

I don't know if this is  the Menus, bootstrap, or PHPs code that's doing this. Here is the code for that carousel-caption:

```html
<?php
    require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Gamesite/core/init.php';

    //
    $SELECT_NEWS = "select * from news limit 4";
    $QUERY_NEWS = $db->query($SELECT_NEWS);


?>
<div class="container-fluid" id="Banner-Container">

        <div class="col-md-12" id="Banner-12-Container">
            <?php while ($NEWS = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QUERY_NEWS)): ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3" id="Banner-Grid-4">
                    <img src="<?php echo $NEWS['news_photo']; ?>" alt="..." class="img responsive" id="Banner_News_Images">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4 id="Banner-Title"><?php echo $NEWS['title']; ?></h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <!-- Add something here .... -->
        </div>

</div>
```

AND the CSS:

```css
#Banner-Container {
  @media screen {
    @media (min-width: 100px)
      and (max-width: 960px) {
        padding-top: 45px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
  }
  padding-top: 65px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#Banner-12-Container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

#Banner-Grid-4 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

  #Banner-Grid-4:hover {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }

#Banner_News_Images {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#Banner_News_Images:hover {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.carousel-caption {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0;
  right: 40%;
  left: 5%;
}

#Banner-Title {
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}

#Banner-Title:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason why:

```
z-index: 9;
```

For `z` planes, you are saying that the text should appear on the 9th. Whereas everything is set to the default (which I believe is zero).

To resolve this, give a higher z-index value to that sidebar's container on the right hand side.

Comment: I made it higher and removed it, still nothing, and yes, it is the caption carousel problem, because when I removed it, the text went behind the menu. But I need the caption carousal to display inside the image though.

Comment: @David  Give a parent element a `z-index` property, so that it's max `z-index` is contained within the parent. With no parent z-index, it will essentially sit on top of any other element. So in this case, your `col-sm-6 col-md-3` could have a `z-index:1` and then the sidebar could have a `z-index:2`.

Comment: I got it, it was actually in the .carousel-caption area of CSS, I just gave it a z-index of 0, and it worked, Thanks though.